# Postfix | MySQL | SSL connection error: error:141A318A:SSL routines:tls_process_ske_dhe:dh key too small

Tags: mysql, openssl, postfix-mta

After upgrading from Ubuntu 18 to Ubuntu 20, Postfix can no longer query my MySQL database and logging the error below.  I've tried several workarounds including change the "CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=1" in /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf, however, I get the same error.

Any help in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

***Error***

warning: connect to mysql server [redacted]: SSL connection error: error:141A318A:SSL routines:tls_process_ske_dhe:dh key too small

Answer (score 4):

I also had this issue and I was able to solve it by using the below parameter in MySQL command

```
--ssl-cipher=AES256-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
```

You can find mroe details about this on this [thread](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/mariadb-5-5-43-and-openssl-1-0-1l-freebsd.52401/)